# Fragment callback to another activity with fragment, results in null pointer at fragment views

Tags: android, callback, android-fragments

So i have an Activity(lets call it A) with a view pager and 3 fragments, one of these fragments(lets call it fragment A) loads a list. The onclickitem list of this list will trigger a callback to the activity(A) so it launchs a new activity(lets call it B) with a new fragment(B too):

Fragment(A) with list, containing the interface and onclickItemListener():

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface onProcessSelectedListener{

    public void onMyProcessSelected(MyProcessDTO process);
}

actualListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        IpdmsMobileMenuItemListDTO dto=(IpdmsMobileMenuItemListDTO) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        if(getView().findViewById(R.id.myprocessdetail)!=null)
                            updateProcess((MyProcessDTO) dto.getDto());
                        else{

                            mListener.onMyProcessSelected((MyProcessDTO) dto.getDto());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

In case the layout doesnt show a specific view it will launch the callback method on the Activity(A) that houses the view pager with this fragment:

```
@Override
public void onMyProcessSelected(MyProcessDTO process) {

    Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyProcessDetail.class);
    showContent.putExtra("Process", process);
    startActivity(showContent);
}
```

Which will call the new activity(B):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    this.setTheme(getThemeId());
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    //get extras from bundle
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(getLayoutId());

    MyProcessDTO process= (MyProcessDTO) extras.get("Process");

    //get fragment
    MyProcessDetailsFragment contentProcess= (MyProcessDetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.view_fragment);

    contentProcess.updateProcess(process);
}
```

The layout loaded in the Activity(B), contains the fragment tag that points to the Fragment(B) class
The Activity(B) calls the fragment(B) method updateProcess():

public void updateProcess(MyProcessDTO process){

```
    nrProcTV.setText(process.getNrprocesso());
    tipoTV.setText(process.getVariante());
}
```

But these textviews are null for some reason. They're initialized on the onActivityCreated method of the fragment(B).:

```
@Override
public void initializeFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.initializeFragment(savedInstanceState);

    nrProcTV=   (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nrprocesso_value);
    tipoTV= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tipoprocesso_value);

}
```

Why hasnt the method onActivityCreated executed before the call to the updateProcess method??

regards,

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textViews are null because you access them before the fragment has gone trough onViewCreated(). You can solve your problem by having the Activity set a field in the Fragment, and let the Fragment use that field to view.setText in its onViewCreated method.

Comment: If that's true,then the getView().findViewById wouldnt work, and it does. IT seems the onActivityCreated method is not finalized when i call the fragment method  from the Activity onCreate ???